# Getting the Right Elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyname

I have a simple little javascript that I have used many times in different forms. It is used with two date pickers so that the selected date in the first date picker is copied to the second one. It looks like this:

```
MouseOver = true;

function date_copy_set() {
    FirstMouseOver = true;
}

function date_copy() {
    if (FirstMouseOver && MouseOver) {
        frames.booking.DepartureDate.value=frames.booking.ArrivalDate.value;
        FirstMouseOver = false;
        MouseOver = false;
    } else {
    }
}
```

Now I have a new application for the script where there are several very similar versions of the form on the page, and I haven't been able to get the script to work. There will be 2 to 8 versions of the form which in simplified form is:

```
<form action="/book/book1.php" method="post" target="_blank"
 id="booking_<?php echo $row_season['season_id'] ?>" name="booking">

<input name="ArrivalDate" id="ArrivalDate" class="datebox"
 size="10" onBlur="date_copy_set()" type="date">

<input name="DepartureDate" id="DepartureDate" class="datebox"
 size="10" onFocus="date_copy()" type="date"> 

<a href="javascript:void()" 
 onclick="frames.booking_<?php echo $row_season['season_id'] ?>.submit()"
 class="buttonPriceBook">Enquire or Book</a></td>

</form>
```

The inclusion of season_id in the id makes sure that all the ids are unique and therefore the submit buttons work. However I can't see a neat way to do the same thing with the script that copies the dates. I have tried various permutations of getElementsByName and getElementsByClassName without any success.

Answer (score 0):

If the inputs in the forms all have the same names, i.e. ArrivalDate and DepartureDate, then you can copy the value from one to the other by passing a reference to the element that called the listener using *this*:

```
<input name="ArrivalDate" ... onblur="date_copy_set(this)" ...>
<input name="DepartureDate" ... onblur="date_copy_set(this)" ...>
```

Now in the method:

```
function date_copy_set(element) {
  if (element.name == 'ArrivalDate') {
    element.form.DepartureDate.value = element.value;
  } else if (element.name == 'DepartureDate') {
    element.form.ArrivalDate.value = element.value;
  }
}
```

so that if the arrival date is changed, it sets the departure date and vice versa.

Note that each input pair must be in a different form, and ID attributes are unnecessary.

Some other stuff—always declare variables:

```
var FirstMouseOver, MouseOver = true;
```

Submitting the form using:

```
<a href="javascript:void()" 
 onclick="frames.booking_<?php echo $row_season['season_id'] ?>.submit()"
 class="buttonPriceBook">Enquire or Book</a>
```

doesn't make any sense to me, just use a submit button. At the very least, don't use an A element with a munged href attribute, use a styled span or other more suitable element.

Comment: This just doesn't work for me. I can see the logic of it, but when I apply it to my page nothing happens. I've also tried making a super-basic page with just your code and minimal stuff around it. Using onClick to submit is so that I can use a custom submit button instead of the bog-standard one.